# In Golang Query PostgreSQL is it possible to do a "fetchall" instead of row by row

Tags: performance, postgresql, go

In some languages when you query a database you have an option to fetch row by row or fetchall and get all results at once.

fetch is more memory efficient but slower overall.

In Go I'd like to fetchall but it seems none of the sql drivers support it.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Thank you in advice

Comment: I am using the DB.Query method. What it appears to do is issue a query but it only grabs one row at a time from postgresql as you loop over rows.Next(). In some languages like PHP they offer fetchAll() which returns all the results at once. This requires more memory but may improve overall speed.

Comment: Using DB.Query from go-pg allows you to read  the entire result into an array without you having to use rows.Next()

Comment: The fetchall method is usually implemented as a convenience method. It just does the iteration over the cursor for you. So there is no real performance gain. My guess is that the Go team didn't implement a fetchall is that it can lead to bad form and that it is trivial to write yourself if needed.

Comment: the underlying io.Reader read method usually yields 4k no matter how large of a buffer you give it (measure it in your own code).  it may have been yielding a whopping 32k when i was transferring GB sized files.  think about what this means.  packets come in, typically with 1500 bytes each.  buffers are there to cover *jitter* in timing of incoming packets.  there is generally no real benefit to having large buffers.  if you wait to fill a giant buffer before streaming back results, you only increase latency and waste memory.  that's why pulling results into memory is not a default stance.

Comment: Note that this does not necessarily mean that there is no buffering at all.  It just means that it's bounded, and correlated with how much data you actually got recently.